# how to use android Fuse api to get location

Tags: android, google-api

how can I use android google API to find current location?
I used this code:

```
GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, 0 , this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
```

But this doesn't work. what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to put this line:

```
googleApiClient.addApi(LocationServices.API)
```

Comment: Excuse me. Could you refer me a good reference for learning android materials?

Comment: You can check developer.android.com. it is the main resource for you.